# Young tableau and Young tabloid together

Tags: tables, diagrams, tabularx, ytableau

I have two questions: (1) How to draw a tabloid with descending two rows such that each row filled with entries
c_{1}(t),
c_{2}(t)
respectively
and then verticle dots and then the last row which consists of only one entry "c_{i}(t)". As I just started learning Tableau package, all what I could do is the following attempt

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\begin{document}
\ytableausetup{tabloids,centertableaux}
$2\cdot\ytableaushort{c_{1}(t),c_{2}(t),\vdots,c_{i}(t)}$
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work with me.

My second question: I also have a tableau (not tabloid) drawn at the same page. However, once I added the above tabloid (using numbers instead of the desired entries "c_{i}(t)") to the same page, both work well but the tableau turned to a tabloid rather than tableau, though I used the proper commands for it as follows

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\begin{document}
\ytableausetup{centertableaux}
 \begin{ytableau}
  2 & 5 & 9 \\
  4 & 8 & 1 \\
  7
  \end{ytableau}
\end{document}
```

Can you please help me on both questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be quite what you want, but you need to put the entries into curly brackets. And then you need to unset the `tabloids` option using `notabloids`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\begin{document}
\ytableausetup{tabloids,centertableaux}
First tableaux:
$2\cdot\ytableaushort{{c_{1}(t)},{c_{2}(t)},{\raisebox{-1.5pt}{\vdots}},{c_{i}(t)}}$

\vdots


Second tableaux:
\ytableausetup{centertableaux,notabloids}
\begin{ytableau}
  2 & 5 & 9 \\
  4 & 8 & 1 \\
  7
\end{ytableau}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marmot for your attempt. But the tabloid is at the top of the page and then after multiple steps I have to draw a tableau (I mean the tableau will appear later). the issue that the commands of a tabloid affected the rows of a tableau and turned it to a tabloid.

Comment: That is great! now it works well.

Comment: Sorry Marmot. Is there a way to adjust the \vdots down a little bit